# Cannot read files from install directory

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, project, installation

I have a wpf application which reads from .xaml files to dynamically create views. However, when installed on a non-dev machine, the program says that the program has unauthorized access to the path where the files are stored. We are using relative pathing to read the files. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where (path) is your program installed on a non-dev machine?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\[Company]\[Product]\Program.exe
The folder where the .xaml files are stored is:
C:\Program Files (x86)\[Company]\[Product]\Views

Answer (score 0):

Only way you'll have granted access to that `Program Files` folder is [Creating and Embedding an Application Manifest (UAC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).

As an example:

```
Executable: IsUserAdmin.exe 
Manifest:IsUserAdmin.exe.manifest
Sample application manifest file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X86"
     name="IsUserAdmin"
     type="win32"/> 
  <description>Description of your application</description> 
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

But you definitively must [go and read the API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).

Comment: Well, off the top of your head, does this make the program run as administrator as in change user id (i.e. run as Admin instead of John)?

Comment: @BlazePhoenix It'll request administrator rights to run. That's what the manifest is for. Otherwise you will require privileges elevation before your call to `ProgramFiles`

Comment: Okay, then perhaps we need to re-evaluate the location of these files, as the program is to be run on log-in/launch of the machine, and asking for admin rights every time would be bad, unless there is a way to update the program to remember that it was given admin rights

Comment: Sure, use AppData for example to store those views.